# Hide scrollbar in Firefox 59.0

Tags: css, firefox, scrollbar, overflow, hidden

Is there a way I can remove or transparent all scrollbar pieces by using CSS in Firefox `59.0`?

The css syntax doesn't work for me: `overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none`.

I ended up trying to solve it as follows:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 30rem;
  height: 22rem;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  border: solid 0.2rem #b2b2c2;
  background-color: LightSlateGray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.scrollport:before,
.scrollport:after {
  content: "";
}

.scrollport {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 9.4rem;
  height: 22rem;
  overflow: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.scrollport:before,
.scrollport:after,
.cell {
  display: block;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 33.3%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrollport">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="scrollport">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="scrollport">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Another attempt involves two divs (`scrollport` and `child`).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 30rem;
  height: 22rem;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  border: solid 0.2rem #b2b2c2;
  background-color: LightSlateGray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.scrollport {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 9.4rem;
  height: 22rem;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child:before,
.child:after {
  content: "";
}

.child {
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: -5rem;
  /* maximum width of scrollbar */
  padding-right: 5rem;
  /* maximum width of scrollbar */
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.child:before,
.child:after,
.cell {
  display: block;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 33.3%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrollport">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="scrollport">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="scrollport">
    <div class="child">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify scrollbar design in Firefox, but if want to hide that scrollbar, Then use `margin-left` negative value.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 30rem;
  height: 22rem;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  border: solid 0.2rem #b2b2c2;
  background-color: LightSlateGray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.scrollport:before,
.scrollport:after {
  content: "";
}

.scrollport {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 9.4rem;
  height: 22rem;
  overflow: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  margin-left: -20px;
  background: LightSlateGray;
}

.scrollport:before,
.scrollport:after,
.cell {
  display: block;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 33.3%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2.4rem;
}

.container:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 21px;
  background: LightSlateGray;
  right: 38px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrollport">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="scrollport">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="scrollport">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems like the only reasonable solution, thanks a lot!